# Reactive behavior in Meteor template

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Could someone clarify how Meteor (Handlebars) templates interact with reactive sources? There is already a lot in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/) but a more systematic explanation would help.

For instance, it seems the following does not trigger a template re-draw when the `Session` variable is changed

```
Template.foo.rendered = function () {
    var selectedItem = Session.get('item_selected');
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

I don't understand why the `Template.rendered` event does not react to reactive source changes. I would also like to understand if other events/methods exhibit this special behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The template will re-render when you set the `item_selected` value with

```
Session.set("item_selected","value");
```

This `Session` hash, beside the name has a reactive dependency similar to [Deps.depends](http://docs.meteor.com/#dependency_depend). When you change this Session hash the current reactive context will be invalidated and everything will be redrawn/re-rendered (which is called via Session.set).

The `.rendered` method will then be run where you can use this new value like you do with `var selectedItem`

For a very detailed videocast on how exactly it works you can have a look at the videos on EventedMind which demonstrate how `Session` is built and how to make another variable reactive.

1. http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-the-reactive-session-object
2. http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-introducing-deps

Comment: Akshat, my question is really about why the behavior that you describe does not apply to the `Template.rendered()` event - and if there are other events/methods following the same pattern

Comment: It does apply everywhere, Template.rendered will be called on each template render which is when the reactive context is invalidated: which a reactive variable changes like Session. I'm not quite sure what you mean the other methods/events change because there wouldn't be a need for alot of methods to re-run as only the Template data/user facing features require a change. Additionally custom events can be added in with Deps.autorun(function() {..}) which is also run when the reactive context is invalidated.

Comment: `Template.rendered` is indeed call each time the template is rendered. But it does not seem to register the reactive source that it contains, like other methods do. In other words:in the example above, if the Session variable changes (and assuming it is not part of any other method linked to the template), the template rendering will not be triggered.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, that isn't the use case for Template.rendered() though, which will only trigger if its respective template was re-rendered if it were changed. Deps.autorun is probably more what you're looking for since you can directly do all the javascript stuff when a dependency changes : http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun